# Is it more efficient to use create_task(), or gather()?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm still at the basics of asynchronous python, and some things confuse me.

```
import asyncio
loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
for variation in args:
    loop.create_task(coroutine(variation))
loop.run_forever()
```

Seems very similar to this

```
import asyncio
loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever(
    asyncio.gather(
        coroutine(variation_1),
        coroutine(variation_2),
        ...))
```

They might do the same thing, but that doesn't seem useful, so what's the difference?

Comment: `run_forever` takes no arguments. Your second example should use `run_until_complete`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your second example should use [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run), not [`run_forever`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_forever).

> They might do the same thing, but that doesn't seem useful, so what's the difference?

`asyncio.gather` is a higher-level construct.

- [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_task) submits the coroutine to the event loop, effectively allowing it to run "in the background" (provided the event loop itself is active). As the name implies, it returns a [*task*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object), a handle over the execution of the coroutine, most importantly providing the ability to [cancel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) it. You can create any number of such tasks in an event loop, and they will all run until their respective completions.
- [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) is for when you are actually interested in the **results** of the coroutines you have spawned. It spawns them as if with `create_task`, allowing them to run in parallel, but also waits for all of them to complete, and then returns their respective results (or raises an exception if any of them raised one).

For example, if you have a `download` coroutine that downloads a URL and returns its contents, and you are downloading a list of URLs, `gather` allows you to match URLs to their data:

```
url_list = [...]
data_list = await asyncio.gather(*[download(url) for url in url_list]

# url_list and data_list now have matching elements, so this works:
for url, data in zip(url_list, data_list):
    ...
```

Doing this with just `create_task` would be somewhat more involved.

Comment: `gather` also allows to cancel all tasks in one `cancel()` command

Comment: @AviahLaor Yes, but be careful because there are cases when that [doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59074112/1600898).

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks for the caveat on doing `cancel()` on gather.

Comment: And mind if I ask why you're still user4815162342 :)

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel Not "still", that username is something I chose, different than the one SO generated for me. :) (The numbers are a silly reference to a now-old TV show.)

Comment: Haha you still recommend watching it? https://www.reddit.com/r/lost/comments/crhxc9/4815162342/

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel It's not to be construed as a recommendation. :)

Comment: What do you mean that it would be somewhat more involved with create_task?
Isn't it just the following? :
```
tasks = [asyncio.create_task(download(url) for url in url_list]
data_list = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```
is the order of tasks not respected?

Comment: @SamuelRodríguez The answer mentions "doing it with **just** `create_task`", which implies not calling `gather`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53710563/1600898) shows an example of such code, and even that is simplified because it doesn't handle edge cases like exceptions and cancellation the way `gather` does.